# When do I need to include Jersey ServletContainer in web.xml to enable JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, java-ee-6

When do I need to include the following snippet in web.xml in order to activate Jersey?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.company.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Is it App. Server dependent if Jersey is activated by default or needs this web.xml entry?

If an App. Server does not require the code above, can I configure the servlet-mapping path, like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey App</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It depends on the version of the Servlet container and the jersey itself. The one you posted is for the 1.x version of jersey. For the newer 2.x versions look at https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.7/user-guide.html#deployment.servlet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am just summarizing the Jersey 2.x docs sent by Bhesh in comment:

### Servlet 2.x Container

(Java EE 5, Glassfish 2.x), you need to hook Jersey as a Servlet.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        ...
    </init-param>
</servlet>
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or a Servlet Filter:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyApplication</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        ...
    </init-param>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyApplication</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

### Servlet 3.x Container

**Descriptorless case**

(Java EE 6, 7; Glassfish 3, 4)There is no need for `web.xml` configuration for the simplest case. Instead an custom `ResourceConfig` class is needed with `@ApplicationPath` annotation for configuration:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
    }
}
```

**Configuring with web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myresources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In this case all the root resource classes (the classes annotated with @Path annotation) as well as any providers that are annotated with @Provider annotation packaged with the application will be automatically registered in the JAX-RS application.